# Haskell: Reading from file to a variable

Tags: haskell

I have the following code in Haskell:

```
import System.IO

data Plaster = Plaster [String] deriving (Read, Show)

main = do putStrLn "Please choose path:"
          path <- getLine
          openn <- openFile path ReadMode
          plaster1 <- hGetLine openn
          let plaster2 = read plaster1::Plaster 
          putStrLn(plaster1)

getFirst :: Plaster -> String
getFirst (Plaster (x:xs)) =  x
getFirst (Plaster []) = []
```

I run main and choose path to a file with single example of `Plaster` instance. Then I would like to apply function `getFirst` to (I wish) variable `plaster2` but I receive: `"Variable not in scope: plaster2"`. What should I do, to read data from file to a variable?

Comment: As posted here, the code doesn't compile, although not with the error message reported in the OP. Please repost the code, ensuring that formatting is correct, as Haskell uses significant whitespace.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Thank you for mentioning that. Now it should compile correctly.

Comment: Indeed, it now compiles. This, however, also means that it doesn't produce the reported compiler error.

Comment: I did not mean, that it produces a compile error. I meant, that after compiling, when I would like to type `getFirst plaster2` in `WinGhci` I receive `Variable not in scope:plaster2`.

Comment: @Czarek That would be because `plaster2` is a local variable to `main`. It isn't visible anywhere outside of it.

Answer (score 1):

In the OP, `main` defines a *function*, the type of which is `IO ()`. This essentially means two things:

- `IO` informs us that the function is impure
- `()` tells us that it returns no data

All named values defined within `main` are only available within that function. We say that they are *scoped* to the `main` function. They are inaccessible outside of the function. This applies not only to `plaster2`, but equally to `path`, `openn`, and `plaster1`.

While you *could* change `main` so that it returns a value, that would be unorthodox; the `main` function is special, as this is usually the entry point for your application.

Instead, I'd suggest that you extract the behaviour that you care about to a separate (impure) function:

```
readFirstLineInFile :: IO Plaster
readFirstLineInFile = do
  putStrLn "Please choose path:"
  path <- getLine
  h <- openFile path ReadMode
  plaster1 <- hGetLine h
  hClose h
  return $ read plaster1
```

Even though I attempted to clean up the code a bit, there are still issues with it, but I don't want to confuse you with that currently.

You can load your code with GHCI and start interacting with this function, as well as the `getFirst` function:

```
*Answer> plaster2 <- readFirstLineInFile
Please choose path:
ploeh.txt
*Answer> getFirst plaster2
"foo"
```

Here, I initiate the `readFirstLineInFile` while binding the return value of it to `plaster2`. Once I've completed the interaction and typed in `ploeh.txt`, the `readFirstLineInFile` function returns, and `plaster2` has a value.

I can now call `getFirst` with `plaster2`, and verify that the result is as expected.

If, however, your overall goal is to be able to interactively test `getFirst`, you don't need to make it so complicated; simply call it in GHCI with various `Plaster` values:

```
*Answer> getFirst $ Plaster ["foo", "bar"]
"foo"
*Answer> getFirst $ Plaster ["foo"]
"foo"
*Answer> getFirst $ Plaster []
""
```

That would be much easier, but I'm not sure if that's your overall goal...